# NSString Comparison Where @"" == nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to compare two strings where I want nil to be equal to a blank string (@""). Right now I'm doing this, which works fine:

```
if ([self.firstName ? self.firstName : @"" isEqualToString:anotherContact.firstName ? anotherContact.firstName : @""]) {
    // They are equal.
}
```

But there seems like there might be something simpler that I'm missing.

I'm not looking for case sensitivity here. If case is different then the test should fail.

Comment: Is it just me or having two ternary operations with a method call in one if statement is a bit too much?

Comment: I kind of like the fewer number of lines I get this way, since I'm checking about ten different string properties. But I totally agree that usually this would be rather ugly. The suggestion by @BryanChen makes this at least look a little cleaner.

Comment: I agree with the other posters that two ternary operators in a single statement is hideous. Just don't do it. I think Josh's solution of a separate method is much cleaner.

Comment: Does the ternary for the receiver even work? I would be very grumpy if I found this in code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[string length]
```

works, but it will return zero if it is nil also. If that's acceptable to you, it's simpler.

btw nested ternary operators are OK in the privacy of your own home, but if you're writing code to share maybe it's better to spread it out a bit so it's obvious.

In response to comments, the way I would do it is like this:

```
    if((([a length] == 0) && ([b length] == 0)) ||
        ([a isEqualToString:b])) {
        // they are equal
    }
```

If either clause succeds then the strings are equal. The second catches any non-nil strings that are actually equal, including `@"" == @""`. The first catches `a` and `b` both `nil`, or one `nil` and one `@""`. I did write the first as `((a == nil) && (b == nil))` at first but you said `@""` should equal nil.

Comment: I'm familiar with -length returning 0 for both nil and @"". How are you suggesting I use it here? I don't see a graceful way.

Comment: I do agree with using the inline tests. Not elegant. But I have a bunch of properties to check, and it makes it easier to read than separate lines I think.

Comment: @DaveBatton I think Adam E. means something like  `NSString * compString=@"";
    if([compString  length]? false : true) {
        
         NSLog(@"compString is nil "  );
    }`

Comment: I'd switch the two expressions on either side of the `||`. You only want to call `isEqualToString:` if both `a` and `b` are not "empty".

Comment: "optimal", I mean. Less pessimal!

Answer (score 12):

you can use `?:` operator. `a ? a : b` is same as `a ?: b` (with side effect of `a` performed once only)

```
if ([self.firstName ?: @"" isEqualToString:anotherContact.firstName ?: @""]) {
    // They are equal.
}
```

Comment: Of course. How'd I miss that? Definitely a step in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I'd write it in this elegant way too. Although I'd probably put those `?:` expressions inside parentheses for readability.

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest a function in this case:

```
NSString * emptyStringIfNil(NSString * s)
{
    if( !s ) return @"";
    else return s;
}
```

---

```
if ([emptyStringIfNil(self.firstName) isEqualToString:emptyStringIfNil(anotherContact.firstName)]) {
    // They are equal.
}
```

Much easier to read. You can do the internals of the function however you want; I'd say the ternary conditional would be reasonable there.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSString*)firstName {
    return _firstName ? _firstName : @"";
}
```

One of the few important reasons for using property getter/setter methods is that it allows you to enforce certain conditions for a property, such as to never be nil.

You can easily ensure that properties such `firstName` are never nil by implementing a custom getter or setter method in a single place, and then you don't have to bother with the weird ternary operators whenever you access such properties.

Comment: Agreed. I write accessor methods often. But in this case it's not important for the values to be non-nil. There may be other reasons to leave them nil. I'm only interested in non-nil values for this specific comparison.

Comment: Easier to use `? :`, e.g. `_firstName ?: @""`. Originally a gnu extension, but supported by clang.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make it a macro? Seems like a perfect use case for it.

Alternatively, you could add a category on NSString: `+string:isEqualToString:`.